# How do I make my world background hdri not blurry?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, world

[image]

I'm having a hard time both making my hdri background not blurry and trying to display the tree from the hdri outside of the window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your HDRI looks blurry because it's heavily stretched (by a factor of 14/1).

This is a world node setup that lets you work independently on an image for lighting and another (the lower chain) for what's seen by the camera.

Consider that lighting needs an HDRI, but it can be small and blurry without any problem, while background image has to be large and detailed but it can be a simple jpg or PNG, as it doesn't need high dynamic range values.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I completely understand.  I need an hdri image for my lighting? and a separate image for my world view?  But I can use a regular jpg for world view image.  I don't know how high that resolution must be as I am choosing high resolution images yet still have blurry image through the window.

Comment: The blurry effect is mainly due to the heavy stretch (in your node setup I read scale 1,1,14). Anyway the background image is mapped onto a large sphere which enclose Blender's environment, so it has to be very detailed to preserve a good quality, 8K pixels should be a starting point, but 8K HDRI are quite heavy, so many artists split the world into two images: one low res but HDRI for lighting, and one HiRes but simple jpg for reflections and background.

Comment: As far as I understand you're not using the image for lighting, so probably you would achieve a better result adding the image as a plane in your scene instead of mapping it on world environment, which is useful expecially for HDRI lighting.